# Increase time interval in Firebase HTTPs Callable iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with my iOS Swift code, and have successfully installed all dependencies.
now, I'm trying to increase timeoutInterval in Firebase function.

```
functions.httpsCallable("getData").call(){ (result, error) in
     guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
      }
     .........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it from client side. You will have to increase the timeout in your functions like thi:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.getData = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  https.onCall((data, ctx) = > {
    // the function
  });
```

> The maximum value for timeoutSeconds is 540, or 9 minutes.

Detailed information can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. at first you have to set time in Firebase server, then in client side(Swift) use this code:

```
functions.httpsCallable("getData").timeoutInterval = 120
```